# Datastore: Failed transactions and rollbacks: What happens if rollback is not called or fails?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

What happens if a transaction fails and the application crashes for other reasons and the transaction is not rolled back?

Also, what happens and how should `rollback` failures be treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the impact of your app's crashes on transaction rollbacks (or any other stateful datastore operation).

The application just sends RPC requests for the operations. The actual operation steps/sequence execution, happens on the datastore backend side, not inside your application.

[From Life of a Datastore Write](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write):

> We'll dive into a bit more detail in terms of what new data is placed
>   in the datastore as part of write operations such as inserts,
>   deletions, updates, and transactions. The focus is on the backend work
>   that is common to all of the runtimes.
>
> ...
>
> When we call `put` or `makePersistent`, several things happen behind
>   the scenes before the call returns and sets the entity's key:
>
> 1. The `my_todo` object is converted into a [protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).
> 2. The [appserver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAMMBP_SacA#t=17m31s) makes an RPC call to the datastore server, sending the entity data in a protocol buffer.
> 3. If a key name is not provided, a unique ID is determined for this entity's key. The entity key is composed of `app ID | ancestor keys |
>      kind name | key name or ID`.
> 4. The datastore server processes the request in two phases that are executed in order: commit, then apply. In each phase, the datastore
>      server identifies the [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf) tablet servers that should receive
>      the data.

Now, depending on the client library you use, transaction rollback could be entirely automatic (in the `ndb` python client library, for example) or could be your app's responsibility. But even if it is your app's responsibility, it's a best-effort attempt anyways. Crashing without requesting a rollback would simply mean that some potentially pending operations on the backend side will eventually time out instead of being actively ended. See also related [GAE: How to rollback a transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700447/gae-how-to-rollback-a-transaction)